# Unreal Asset export : vertex-shader

Tags: fbx, export, vertex-shader

I have an Unreal asset, and we need to convert or replicate a similar visual appearance in Unity.

Initially, we started converting the Unreal asset into FBX. Used MAYA to reload the content with relative textures and maps.
As a result, the colour scheme I see on the buildings in the Unreal engine is not the same in MAYA.
Few of the known experts said that in Unreal they might have used vertex colour for the polygons.

Question:

1. Can we apply a vertex colour in the Unreal engine? if you have a huge scene, how can we control assigning the wall colour (vertex colour)?
2. If there is an option to add the vertex colour, How can I read that data(Information) in Unreal?
3. Is it possible to export these properties in any form of data? so that we can load and replicate(duplicate the effect done to get a different wall colour) in MAYA?
4. Is it possible to make the identical scene in Unity by using Unreal asset?

I am very curious to know the answers to the above questions, any answers from you can provide an insight for us to look for the solution from a different angle.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: Please try to ask one question at a time. Many devs are experts in Unreal OR Unity, but few are experts in both, so you'll have much more success asking just question 1 or just question 4, than trying to make a single post cover both 1 and 4 together. You can always post a second question if what you still need more help after the answers to the first.

Comment: Also, [this article is the top search result for "Unreal vertex colour"](https://docs.unrealengine.com/en-US/BuildingWorlds/LevelEditor/Modes/MeshPaintMode/VertexColor/MaterialSetup/Color/index.html). This seems to answer question 1 and 2. I find similarly useful results when searching "Maya vertex colour" or "Unity vertex colour" so this looks like a topic you can answer for yourself with just a little research. Want to give that a try, and edit your question to focus just on the first step you haven't been able to find in your research to date?